# How to block previous steps on Bootstrap Fuelux Wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fuelux

In my app, the previous steps must be blocked. Step one not should be accessible after validated and submited. How to block previous steps of manual selection?

Current implementation, example:

```
<div class="wizard clearfix" data-initialize="wizard" id="form-wizard">
    <ul class="steps">
        <li data-target="#step1" data-step="1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span>Register</li>
        <li data-target="#step2" data-step="2"><span class="badge">2</span>Other</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="step-content text-left">
    <div data-step="1" id="step1" class="step-pane active">
        <form id="frmSignup1">
            ...
            <input type="button" class="btn-next" data-target="#step2" data-wizard="next" data-last="Finish" value="Próximo">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-step="2" id="step2" class="step-pane">
        <form id="frmSignup2">
            ...
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

The attr data-restrict wasn't working in version that I was using. I changed to latest fuelux version and works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the `data-restrict` attribute?

Per the [`wizard` documentation](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/javascript.html#wizard) the `restrict` attribute will "Prevents the user from navigating to a previous step."

Here's the basic usage:

```
<div class="wizard" data-initialize="wizard" id="myWizard" data-restrict="previous">
```

---

**Snippet Example:**

*Uses the example markup from the Fuel UX documentation*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.0.2/css/fuelux.min.css">
  <script src="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.0.2/js/fuelux.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="fuelux">
  <div class="wizard" data-initialize="wizard" id="myWizard" data-restrict="previous">
    <ul class="steps">
      <li data-step="1" class="active"><span class="badge">1</span>Campaign<span class="chevron"></span>
      </li>
      <li data-step="2"><span class="badge">2</span>Recipients<span class="chevron"></span>
      </li>
      <li data-step="3"><span class="badge">3</span>Template<span class="chevron"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="actions">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>Prev</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-last="Complete">Next<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="step-content">
      <div class="step-pane active sample-pane alert" data-step="1">
        <h4>Setup Campaign</h4>
        <p>Veggies es bonus vobis, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi welsh onion daikon amaranth tatsoi tomatillo melon azuki bean garlic. Beetroot water spinach okra water chestnut ricebean pea catsear courgette.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="step-pane sample-pane bg-info alert" data-step="2">
        <h4>Choose Recipients</h4>
        <p>Celery quandong swiss chard chicory earthnut pea potato. Salsify taro catsear garlic gram celery bitterleaf wattle seed collard greens nori. Grape wattle seed kombu beetroot horseradish carrot squash brussels sprout chard.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="step-pane sample-pane bg-danger alert" data-step="3">
        <h4>Design Template</h4>
        <p>Nori grape silver beet broccoli kombu beet greens fava bean potato quandong celery. Bunya nuts black-eyed pea prairie turnip leek lentil turnip greens parsnip. Sea lettuce lettuce water chestnut eggplant winter purslane fennel azuki bean earthnut
          pea sierra leone bologi leek soko chicory celtuce parsley jÃ­cama salsify.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```